# Prevent Google Contact Sync in Work Profile on Android 10

Tags: contacts, google-account

Imagine the current situation:
With the help of Shelter (https://github.com/PeterCxy/Shelter) I created a work profile. I want to use this work profile as a container with less personal data than my main profile.
For this reason I deactivated the "com.google.android.syncadapters.contact" app.
With this setup I was able to add my Google account inside the work profile without having my contacts get downloaded on the device in this profile.

On Android 10 however this doesn't work anymore. The syncadapter is still deactivated (frozen) but the contacts sync nevertheless.

I'm aware of the fact that I can manually disable the sync in the settings of the work profile.
However I need a solution that a) can prevent the sync before adding the account (since the first sync already happened when I add the account and then go to settings) and b) can be done programatically since I'm writing my own app based on this.

So my question is if any of you pros know where the contact sync mechanism (of a google account) is defined since Android 10 and if you see another possibility to disable this again.

Regards,
David